# How should we handle tagging of board games with different editions?

Tags: discussion

Board games are hanging around long enough these days that newer editions of them are being released with vastly different mechanics. For example, Arkham Horror 3rd Edition has been recently released and it is very different to the 2nd edition which all of the current questions are about.

Should the existing tag be changed to arkham-horror-second-ed or something along those lines?

Answer (score 4):

A new tag should be added for the new edition and existing tags can be updated as needed if they only apply to an older edition. There will always be questions that can apply to all editions and those should still get a general tag.