# How should we tag old questions that don't specify an editon?

Tags: discussion, support

[Can a Space Marine army consist of units from different chapters?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/4275/can-a-space-marine-army-consist-of-units-from-different-chapters/8460#8460) has a generic question to which the answer varies by edition (quite significantly in this case).

[How should we handle tagging of board games with different editions?](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1766/how-should-we-handle-tagging-of-board-games-with-different-editions) says we should use edition tags:

> A new tag should be added for the new edition and existing tags can be updated as needed if they only apply to an older edition. There will always be questions that can apply to all editions and those should still get a general tag.

Should we tag questions like the linked WH40k question with an old edition, and have new questions for new editions, or should we have a one-stop shop type answer for that question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the current consent on version-specific tags?](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1807/what-is-the-current-consent-on-version-specific-tags)

Comment: @JoeW not really. This is not about new questions, this is about editing old questions.

Comment: I don't see how that wouldn't apply here, in the end we can't specify a version unless we have evidence in the question about what version it applies to.

Comment: @JoeW at the time of asking only 6th edition was out, is that enough evidence?

Comment: How do you know it was 6th edition and not 5th? Also how do you know the question isn't still valid as it hasn't changed in any of the newer editions?

Comment: @JoeW as I stated in the question, the answer varies a lot depending on the edition, I know that because I've researched it.

Comment: I acknowledge that the answer can vary a  lot depending on the edition, what I am saying is that you can't always determine what edition the question is talking about unless it specifies it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless the version is specified in the question we shouldn't add version tags to a question. Even if you know the current version at the time of the question was 6th edition you don't know that is the version the person has and is asking about. If there is something in the question that can narrow it down to a specific version such as a mechanic that was only around for that edition it would be different.